# Erro Aurelius ORM The column 'A_ItemCode' was specified multiple times for 'tempset'

Tags: delphi

I am using TMS Aurelius in the test version for Delphi 10.2 Tokyo.
I am using it in conjunction with TMS XData.

Au use Paging to retrieve data from DB I have received the following error

The column 'A_ItemCode' was specified multiple times for 'tempset'.

It is clear that there was duplication in the Alias of the ItemCode field.
This only happened after I made a Class membership.

The error happens by using Paging.

Is it an Aurelius bug or am I doing something wrong?

Follows the code of the Classes in question:

```
  type
    [Entity]

    [Table('W_SF_ITEM_ESTOQUE')]
    [Id('FItemCode', TIdGenerator.none)]
    TItem = Class(TPersistent)

  private
    {...}
    [Column('ItemCode', [])]
    FItemCode : String;

    [Column('ItemName', [], 80)]
    FItemName: String;

    [Association]
    [JoinColumn('ItemCode', [])]
    FEstoqueFisico: TEstoqueFisicoItem;
 {...}
```

SQL generated by Aurelius, note that there are two A_ItemCode field:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
            ) AS rownum
        ,A.ItemCode AS A_ItemCode
        ,A.ItemName AS A_ItemName
        ,A.U_SF_TIPO AS A_U_SF_TIPO
        ,A.U_SF_COLECAO AS A_U_SF_COLECAO
        ,A.OnHand AS A_OnHand
        ,A.Price AS A_Price
        ,A.PrecoMinimo AS A_PrecoMinimo
        ,A.PicturName AS A_PicturName
        ,A.ItemCode AS A_ItemCode
        ,B.ItemCode AS B_ItemCode
        ,B.WhsCode AS B_WhsCode
        ,B.WhsName AS B_WhsName
        ,B.OnHand AS B_OnHand
    FROM W_SF_ITEM_ESTOQUE A
    LEFT JOIN ESTOQUE_FISICO_ITEM B ON (B.ItemCode = A.ItemCode)
    ) AS tempset
WHERE rownum BETWEEN 61
        AND 90
```

Comment: What's the point of the "Run code snippet" in your q?

Comment: Well, clearly there are two `A_ItemCode` fields, because you've referenced `ItemCode` twice (once as `[Column]` and once as an `[Associated][JoinColumn]`. Have you tried asking in the TMS groups first?